# Does anyone know what this kinda apps are called (Apps with drawers)?

Tags: ios, user-interface

Does anyone know what these kinda apps are called and where I could find a template of something similar to this : http://gyazo.com/9cd65ef7e86376705d29519e9ba900b2.png those apps with the 'drawers' such as the Facebook app and the 9GAG app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is called IIViewDeckController, located [here.](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)
Pretty simple to use and it's used by a lot of big-time apps. I highly recommend it!

Comment: We call this the "slider menu".  I believe this was coined by facebook

Answer (score 1):

I have heard it referred to as a hamburger menu app. Here is a link to a user interface discussion about this style. Hope this helps!

https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/32877/what-is-this-side-menu-called-that-can-be-found-in-many-multi-touch-apps-and-wh

Also,here is another framework I have used recently that works well:

https://github.com/edgecase/ECSlidingViewController